# Sargan–Hansen test or Sargan's $J$ test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, econometrics

What does the J-Test, that is used in GMM, identyfy? It is based on the chi-square distribution and it is also well known as Sargan–Hansen test or Sargan's $J$ test. What it means if the p-value is too low, close to zero, or too high close to $1$. In general, what is the intuition behind this test?